# Tawk.to Not working inside an IONIC App but working on deployed browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to integrate Tawk.to in my ionic app but the widget is not showing at all in my app. But, when i do ionic serve and run it on browser the widget shows correctly.
Is it because ionic app is not allowing an iframe to load?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
 (function(){
  var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
   s1.async=true;
   s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/.../default';
   s1.charset='UTF-8';
   s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*'); 
   s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);

  })();
  </script>
  <!--End of Tawk.to Script-->
   </div>
```

Comment: HI, I am doing the same thing but it's not working when my app runs on a mobile device. Did you find any solution for this? @Sourav

Comment: @Blu Nope still no solution for this, Let me know if you find one.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution on this? Been trying to add tawk plugin since yesterday.

Comment: @RamGuiao No, haven't found it till now. Been using it as an external link

Comment: @SouravDas Have you tried to generate an APK? is it working? I am using Ionic 2 by the way.

Comment: @RamGuiao i generated apk but still didnt work. So, i used inappbrowser to open the direct link

Comment: is working on android, but not on ios.

Comment: @MarioLopes can you kindly post your github code link to check

Comment: it's plugin "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
using the version spec="^1.1.16" works android and ios

Comment: did anyone solve this? I cant get Tawk To to work in an ionic capacitor production build.

Answer (score 0):

So after debugging this a bit I am pretty sure this is due to the `Origin` header being set to a domain with the `ionic://` scheme on iOS.

My assumption is that tawk.to does not handle this properly as I see the `/register/:id` request failing on iOS (but not in the browser). Android does have a `http://` scheme, whereas iOS does not allow this:

> Values like http, https or file are not valid and will use default value instead. ([1](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview#ios-preferences))

So for the actual solution, I suggest using the direct chat link ([2](https://www.tawk.to/knowledgebase/chat-widget/direct-chat-link/)) feature:

> The Direct chat link allows you to add a special link to your website that will make your selected Widget open in a new browser window.

Either use the In App Browser plugin ([3](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser)) or just pop in a link in the app and have it open in the system browser (be sure to correctly configure your intent whitelist (see [4](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/#intent-whitelist)).

Comment: You have 0 control over the fields using direct link. Direct link eliminates possibility to for example pre-fill email.

Comment: Direct link also doesn't alert the user when new messages come in. Could result in bottle necks for support teams. I hope to find a solution here for Tawk To Capacitor Ionic

Answer (score -1):

put in your config.xml
...

```
   ...
   <access origin="*" />
   <allow-intent href="*" />
   <allow-navigation href="*" />
   ...
   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^1.1.16" />
```